# How to solve this solution with DB

Tags: sql-server, database, architecture

I have a table `Users` (`UserID, FirstName, LastName...`) and a table `Messages`. Table `Messages` stores messages, which are sent between users.

So, I can create this table like:

`Messages (SenderID, ReceiverID...)` and create 2 FK to `Users`, but this approach seems is incorrect and does not allow to make cascade delete/update for FK.

Multiple messages are not allowed.
Also, I can't set "Set Null" for both relationships. Why? It would be very good.

Which structure is correct in this case?

Comment: cascade delete! Not on my watch...!

Comment: I prefer to have an application emit explicit deletes. Not a fan of related records 'disappearing'

Comment: Because `ON DELETE CASCADE` means, that if User #17 sends a message to User #18, and at a later point you delete User #18, the message will disappear from User #17's outbox.

Comment: yes, I understand it and it depends on bussines-rules. In any case, this architecture with 2 tables is correct?

Comment: The correctness depends on your business needs. For example, is it possible in your system that a message is sent to multiple receivers - as in emails? If so than this structure won't work. 

This structure is quite rigid but will be quick in fetching messages.

So need to find answer to similar questions. If you post exact requirement, than a better solution can be devised.

Comment: The structure is correct, i can see no other solution best than this one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the problem from the users perspective.

Do you think that the receiver wants it's message deleted when the sender deletes it's message from the outbox?

No. In other words: Create one copy of the message for each user.

> Multiple messages are not allowed

Insane requirement. It IS two different messages.